# Why is my JFrame displaying nothing?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon; 
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MAIN_FILE extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        int x, y;
        int colMax = 29;
        int rowMax = 41;

        super.paintComponent(g);
        ImageIcon ground = new ImageIcon("C:\\Programming\\Ground.jpg");

        for(col = 0; col <= colMax; col++)
        {
            for(row = 0; row <= rowMax; row++)
            {
                x = row * 30;
                y = col * 30;
                ground.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);
            }
        }
        ImageIcon wall = new ImageIcon("C:\\Programming\\WallTest0000.jpg");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JPanel JP = new JPanel();
        JP.setVisible(true);
        JFrame jf =  new JFrame();
        jf.setTitle("Dungeon Thing");
        jf.setSize(1230, 870);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.add(JP);
    }
```

Comment: I'm noticing that the `main()` method never uses the class it's in (`MAIN_FILE`).

Comment: Java class names should be camelcase nouns. Accordingly, `MAIN_FILE` should be renamed to `Main`, or `MainFile` at the very least.

Comment: `ImageIcon ground = new ImageIcon("C:\\Programming\\Ground.jpg");`  By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.  Also, we should never be trying to load image in a painting method.  They should be loaded at start-up and cached as class attributes.

Answer (score 3):

After adding the `JPanel`, you need to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the `JFrame`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(new JLabel("Label"));
    frame.revalidate();
    frame.repaint();
}
```

Note, if you added the component to the frame before calling `setVisible` like David said, you wouldn't need `revalidate()` or `repaint()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(new JLabel("Label"));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Comment: `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` For frame positioning, you cannot go by `setLocationByPlatform(true)`.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556) for demo. `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` Better to use `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`.. +1 otherwise.

Comment: Or, if possible, call `setVisible` last

Comment: OP called for `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` but not any frame positioning, so I should've omitted that.

Answer (score -1):

Once you call `jf.setVisible(true)`, the **event dispatch thread** will be locked, waiting for something to happen.

The call to `jf.add(JP)` doesn't even happen until after the window has been disposed of.

Try reordering your operations in main to add the `JPanel` to the `JFrame` first, then `setVisible(true)`

Comment: This is untrue. `public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        System.out.println("Here");
    }`

Comment: And another: `public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JLabel("Label"));
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
    }`

Comment: @TAsk  The statement in the first paragraph of this answer only applies to modal windows such as a modal dialog or an option pane.  The rest is wrong because of that error.